# Strange 1px offset when using :after

Tags: css

[Code here](http://dabblet.com/gist/2915854)

Very strange, no idea why it's happening, i seems to come from the center element (h9), but no idea why... anyone?

Answer (score 1):

just replace `left:100%;` with `right:2px;` to solve the problem (and `right:106%;` with `left:-11px` on your `:before`). [see it working](http://dabblet.com/gist/2915891).

this solves the problem, but sadly i can't really expain (jet) whats causing the gap in your initial layout.

Answer (score 0):

h1 to h6 are valid html tags, h9 is not.

This is probably causing your problem.

Comment: you're right with your first statement, but this isn't the problem here - just edit the code to see the same problem happening with `h1`, for example.